# Excel UDF formula does not appear

Tags: excel, user-defined-functions

I have an Excel UDF . It is written in C# and the automation addon has been packaged using the Visual Studio setu up project wizard. The addon loads in the list of automation addons available but the formula does not appear in the Insert function formula dialogue box.

I used Office 2003 and Visual Studio 2008 to build the addin. The client machine has .Net Framework 2.0 installed and does not have any installation of VS.

Should I have to enable the udf specifically somewhere ? This problem appears only when I am packaging the addon to distribute it to a client machine.

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fact that the COM add-in appears in the availale list of automation add-ins would imply that the COM add-in has been successfully registered on the target machine.

Could it be a Trust issue?  You can check the level of trust your assembly has using the Microsoft .NET Framework Configuration: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/815147

I suspect you'll need full-trust.

I haven't built add-ins with COM for a while (I can list the alternatives if you like), so let me know if this doesn't fix it and I'll look into it further.

Comment: Hi Chris,

Thanks a lot for your response. I set the trust property to grant full trust in my assembly and then rebuilt the set up project to distribute. The udf now appears in the formula bar.

Thanks,

Comment: Great to be of help. One thing - it would help other users if you could mark my answer as a correct answer. Otherwise this question will appear to be 'unanswered'.  All the best, Chris